# Allow annotation only for specific methods

Tags: java, annotations

I've implemented some custom runtime method annotation. Now I want to check (preferably in compile-time) that all methods which were marked with my newly implemented annotation are static and have only one serializable argument. How can I archive it in Java 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotation processing to do that. Run [javac with proc, processor and processorpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) option and implement a [Processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) that does all the checking you want.

Note that you can't enforce others to use these options, so you should still include appropriate runtime checking.